# i need to change my listview to extend baseAdapter using the ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-listview, arraylist

i have an activity that use list view and display values after fetching from mysql database the application work fine but now i wnat to changed the list activity to extends BaseAdapter because i need to add in the row 2 text view.

can anyone help me to make this change  ????

this is my code

## User.java

```
package com.devleb.loginDemo;

import java.util.Date;

public class User {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    Date date;
}
```

## CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.devleb.loginDemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static ArrayList<User> usersList;

    // private static ArrayList name, date;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    String[] userName;
    Date[] createdDate;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<User> result, Context c) {
        usersList = result;
        context = c;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return usersList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return usersList.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = null;

        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView txtCreateDate = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.txtCreateDate);

        txtCreateDate.setText(usersList.get(position).getDate().toString());

        TextView txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);

        txtName.setText(usersList.get(position).getName());
        return row;
    }

}
```

**now how to add this custom adapter to my UserListActivity ???**

## UserListActivity.java

```
package com.devleb.loginDemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UserListActivity extends ListActivity {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;

    private static String url_display_user = "http://10.0.3.2/android_connect/display_user.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";

    private static final String TAG_USERS = "userlist";

    private static final String TAG_USER = "user";
    private static final String TAG_DATE = "create_date";


    // private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

    // employees JSONArray
    JSONArray users = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list);

        usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new getUserList().execute();

        // getListView
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                // String id = ((TextView)
                // view.findViewById(R.id.uid)).getText()
                // .toString();

                // Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), StatusList.class);
                // in.putExtra(TAG_ID, uid);

                // startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }

    class getUserList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            UserListActivity.this.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> parametres = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_display_user,
                    "GET", parametres);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Users: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);

                    // looping through All Users
                    for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = users.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String user = c.getString(TAG_USER);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_USER, user);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        usersList.add(map);

                    }
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {

                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            if (result != null) {

                UserListActivity.this
                        .setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(UserListActivity.this,
                        usersList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                TAG_USER }, new int[] { R.id.uid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**i know that the change must be done in OnPostExecute()**

Comment: the change should be done in getView if you want to change what you see...

Answer (score 0):

Is that your problem??

```
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static ArrayList<User> usersList;

        // private static ArrayList name, date;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        String[] userName;
        Date[] createdDate;
        Context context;

        public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String> result, Context c) {
            usersList = result;
            context = c;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return usersList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return usersList.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup parent) {
            //Get the HashMap
            HashMap<String,String> map = userList.get(position);

            //do what ever you want with the hashmap
            return row;
        }

    }
```

Comment: no as you see in my code for the BaseAdapter i am initialize a  **private static ArrayList<User> usersList;**  and the constructor for this customAdapter take as argument arrayList   where in my **UserListActivity** i need to have and **hashMap** **(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;)** because the arrayList DO NOT handle HashMap  so how to fix this error that what i am asking for.

Comment: So you are asking for how to handle a hashmap in BaseAdapter? You only have to read the data from the hashmap in getView.
The BaseAdapter need not to handle a hashmap because you have an ArrayList. The item in it is a hashmap. So you can read every single hashmap in getview. AND startn an UI-Thread and create the listView/Activity new to see the result because you are in an asynctask

Comment: but the constructor of my CustomAdapter will have a **ArrayList<User>** as an argument where i need to have an **ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>** to handle the **JSON nodes as a key** and the **Strings  as a values**  did you understand what i mean ??

Comment: Yes. I do not see the problem. Change the constructor. Give  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> or even both in it. I edited my answer.